# How to handle DELETEs in database (moving the deleted entity to an archive table)?

Tags: sql, database

We have a PostgreSQL-driven database for our information system we are currently developing. Since the issue of deletions is something I've been reluctant to solve completely, it starts to bother me as the project already started, the database is slowly being filled and there comes a point when users will actually want to delete the non-relevant data.

In our case, what will get deleted by users are some kind of 'jobs' we do for our clients. Once a job has been finished, users usually do not want to have it listed on the web page, so they will delete it. At first (when the system was in testing phase so no harm could have been done), user's delete was a real DELETE from the database. Because it was nicely set to cascade to the very bottom of our entity graph, it really deleted everything. And also took a lot of time. Now that we started using the system for real, I was afraid of accidental deletions and I made it impossible for users to delete anything.

I think that the most important question is "What exactly does 'deletion' of a job mean in our business domain?" In our case, there are two points to this:

- Users do not want to see the job listed anymore (unless they explicitly request for a list of old jobs, which I therefore have to keep)
- Some of the job's data are gone for good and only some basic overview of the job's status is kept

I've read many articles about why soft delete is good and a lot about why it is not (e.g. [here](http://ayende.com/blog/4157/avoid-soft-deletes)). What seems to me as a better alternative is to have the deleted job moved to some archive table. At the same time, I would delete the job's data which will be no longer needed. The nice consequence of this is that I will not have to adjust all my queries to handle some kind of "DeletedOn" column and the main job table will not be cluttered with inactive jobs.

The problem I have with this is more of a technical one: assuming I **still** need to keep some references from other entities to the deleted job, what is the best way to do that? Because I have foreign keys to the job table set up in other entities, I can't just move the job to another table, DB would not let me.

What is the usual and well tested approach to this?

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I would just move everything to archive tables and delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF I understand you correctly then you have some sort of "Jobs" in the DB and can't delete all related information but need to keep some part of them there...

There are two options that I use in such cases:

- Add a Job state field
  This field can have different values like new/in progress/waiting/deliviered/deleted... once you change your code to accomodate for this new field you have a lot of flexibility... you can offer filters based on the Job State for the user in the UI etc.
- Add a DeleteOn field and hide it
  You rename the table, add the field and create a view with the same name as the original table which filters out all records with DeleteOn set... the view gets a trigger (ON DELETE) which just sets that field for the respective job... no cascading delete, no cluttering/changing code etc. IF need be you can always extend the trigger to move all or part of the rows which have DeleteOn set to archive tables...

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you whats the usual and well tested approach for this, i can only tell you what worked for me.

We agree on the fact that no data should be lost for various reasons (auditing, historic archiving, etc), so we are seeing two possible outcomes for this:

- Move the data
- Flag the data as deleted and filter it with every query

Now is a matter of what is more expensive to you.

- Moving the data:
  Here you will need another table(s) (or an OLAP database maybe?) to persist all the deletions. The first cost that comes to my mind is the one of a double maintenance. If you add a column to one table, you have to add it to the historic table (or update the ETL job and the target table). Every change you make to your ERD will have to be made twice.
- Flaggin the data:
  Update all you current queries to consider the flag. This can be painful, but its a one timmer (and in most of the cases will be a `WHERE deleted = 0`)
  Some ORMs provide nice approaches for solving this issue without having you to manually change your queries. 
  The other issue is one you also mention, your tables will be 'dirty'. This may or may not be  a performance problem depending on the amount of data you generate.

The times I considered benefits/costs for each alternative I've always chosen to use soft deletion, so now it's up to what is more expensive in your case.